# Problems with ASIHTTPRequest and jpeg Upload

Tags: ios, image, ipad

When I do the following with an .png file, everything works fine.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setTag:APICreateUserRequestType];


picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(picture, 1.0);
[request setData:imageData withFileName:@"profilepic.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"picture"];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

But if I choose a jpg image just like above, it crashed on "startAsynchronous" with BAD ACCESS.

What is my mistake?

chris

Comment: can you mention which line does it throw the BAD_ACCESS error.